Is it possible to cast to a generic interface with an interface as a type argument
If I have the following interfaces / classes:
public interface ICutleryInfo
{
   string Metal { get; set; }
}

public class KnifeInfo : ICutleryInfo
{
   public string Metal { get; set; }

   public int NumberOfTeeth { get; set; }
}

public interface ICutlery<T> where T : ICulteryInfo
{
   T CutleryInfo { get; set; }
}

public class Knife : ICutlery<KnifeInfo>
{
   public KnifeInfo CutleryInfo { get; set; }

   public Knife()
   {
       CutleryInfo = new KnifeInfo();
   }
}

Now I want to create an instance of Knife (without knowing it's a Knife at compile time), so I use Activator.CreateInstance(). But while I don't know it's a Knife, I do know it's an ICutlery.
What I've tried is as follows, but I get an invalid cast exception.
// Somehere else... 
var cutleryType = typeof(Knife);

// etc. etc. then... 

var cutleryInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(cutleryType);
var cutlery = (ICutlery<ICutleryInfo>)cutleryInstance;   // Runtime error - invalid cast exception.
cutlery.CutleryInfo.Metal = "Silver";

There is no problem creating the instance, and if I try to cast to ICutlery<KnifeInfo> it works no problem (but this isn't what I need at this point). Is this possible? And if so, how should it be approached?

Does the CutleryInfo property need to have a setter? If not, you can make the interface covariant.

ICulterry isn't co-variant, so even if KnifeInfo inherits or implements ICuteryInfo, that doesn't mean anything to ICulterry<T>. In other words: a ICultery<Derived> isn't a ICultery<Base>. As Sweeper mentioned you may make the interface co-variant, however you need to make it imuutable by removing its setter.

Totaly irrelevant sidenote. ICutleryInfo has a metal property but my knifes are made from ceramic.

@komodosp, Do you need to have setter in ICutlery<T>? If not, you can remove it and use out generic modifier on T param like: ICutlery<out T>. And your cast operation will work :)

What you're trying to do is akin to this: Bowl<IFruit> bowl = new Bowl<Apple>(); bowl.Add(new Banana());. That is clearly illegal.

No, not with your current interfaces, because it would allow someone to do:
ICutlery<ICutleryInfo> knife = new Knife();
knife.CutleryInfo = new ForkInfo(); // Wont work! Knife.CutleryInfo must be a KnifeInfo.

You can fix this by removing the setter and making your interface covariant:
public interface ICutlery<out T> where T : ICutleryInfo
{
    T CutleryInfo { get; }
}
...
ICutlery<ICutleryInfo> knife = new Knife();

Trying to keep objects immutable is usually a good idea for several reasons, or at least restrict how objects can change state. If you for some reason cannot remove the setter you probably need to reconsider your overall design.

You can inherit ICutlery<ICutleryInfo> as second interface:
public class Knife : ICutlery<KnifeInfo>, ICutlery<ICutleryInfo>
{
    public KnifeInfo CutleryInfo { get; set; }
    ICutleryInfo ICutlery<ICutleryInfo>.CutleryInfo
    {
        get => this.CutleryInfo;
        set => this.CutleryInfo = (KnifeInfo)value;
    }

    public Knife()
    {
        CutleryInfo = new KnifeInfo();
    }
}


With set method implementation showing why you should not do that)

@GuruStron Yea, I know, but this is just easy "not perfect" solution. In some cases, will be fine

This will not be a fine solution in any case.
